# Dock tile plug-ins for not running applications

Tags: objective-c, osx-snow-leopard

Is the dock tile plug-in of an application used even when the application is not active?

The documentation says that the dock tile plug-in is used when the application is loaded in the dock. Does it mean the application is running, or the application is put in the dock because the user wants it to stay in the dock?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation states that:

> Your Dock tile plug-in continues to run as long as your application’s tile is in the Dock, even if your application is actually running.

If you've written one, then it should be a simple enough matter to test and see for yourself.